# How to check ASP.NET Core RC2/1.0 Razor views for compile errors?

Tags: asp.net-core

Razor view precompilation [has been removed from RC2](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3917) due to [issues with getting it to work in .NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3993#issuecomment-175155831).

Is there a way to fail a CI build if there's a syntax error in one of the .cshtml files, or will this not be possible until precompilation is back?

(I'm testing this on the HelloMvc project from [ASP.NET CLI samples](https://github.com/aspnet/cli-samples). The `Views\Home\Index.cshtml` file can have literally anything in it and `dotnet build` will still succeed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current RC2 build system seems to completely ignore the `Compiler/Preprocess` folder - you can literally put anything in it and it will generate no build errors. Until Roslyn is wired back up to do precompilation, I don't think it's currently possible to check .cshtml files in the build stage.

The only workaround I've found is to get Visual Studio to open *every* .cshtml file in the project using some dirty fine/replace tricks, and have the Intellisense engine check the razor code.

**Update**

Looking at the [commit that removed razor precompilation](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/commit/c05551e16770c1396068036bc96d68025ebdf3f5), it seems that the entire `RazorPreCompileModule` itself was actually removed, and [won't be back for some time](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3993#issuecomment-175765226). Even if this code was added back into your project manually, it doesn't look like dotnet build will run any compile modules.

**Update 2**

View Compilation is back in ASP.NET Core 1.1!

To enable it, add the following into the project.json "dependencies" section:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Design": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
}
```

and the following to your "tools" section:

```
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools”: “1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
}
```

and under "scripts", add the razor-precompile command to "postpublish":

```
"scripts": {
    "postpublish": [
        "dotnet razor-precompile -configuration %publish:Configuration% -framework %publish:TargetFramework% -output-path %publish:OutputPath% %publish:ProjectPath%"
    ]
}
```

**Update 3 - csproj**

We finally got around to moving to VS2017 and performing the project migration to csproj. This of course broke razor precompilation, and boy was it a rabbit hole to figure out how to fix it - the [official instructions are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation).

The first hiccup you'll probably hit is the automated xproj/project.json -> csproj migration failing. The automated migration will fail if you have a `postpublish` script section in your `project.json`, so go ahead and completely delete that section before you do the migration.

As it turns out, you can still run post publish scripts by adding `<Target Name="PostPublishTarget" AfterTargets="Publish">...</Target>` to your `.csproj`, but this is now unnecessary for razor precompilation anyway. So without further ado, here's how to enable razor precompilation in VS2017/csproj land, once you've migrated your project:

1. Add the correct view compilation package reference to your csproj. In the `<ItemGroup>` containing all of your project's `<PackageReference>` tags, add:

   `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="1.1.0" />`
2. Add the MvcRazorCompileOnPublish property to your csproj. In the `<PropertyGroup>` section containing your project `<VersionPrefix>`, `<TargetFramework>` etc, add:

   `<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>`

And you're done. The build system will now run razor precompilation every time the project is published. You should see something like `Razor view compilation for myApp -> obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\myApp.PrecompiledViews.dll` in your build output when publishing.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this now that ASP Core projects have moved back to csproj format?

Comment: @Ryan this one is for publish. what about normal build/compile?

Comment: @MoHradA I haven't found a supported method for doing this on build, there is no `<MvcRazorCompileOnBuild>` tag. It doesn't look like a post build target would work either, since the razor-precompile command no longer works.

Comment: @Ryan I did everything you said but it doesn't reveal errors in views when the project is rebuilt.

Comment: @Sergey It only attempts to build the razor pages on Publish, not Build unfortunately.

Comment: @Ryan thanks, I guess it yet. It's better than nothing.