# How to compile views as a syntax checking in ASP.NET Core MVC 1?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express

I would like to have a compile-time validation of the views. In my old web application, written for MVC 5, I have these entries located in the `csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
  <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

It worked as expected.

Now, I have placed exact the same entries in the `xproj` file of my new web application (ASP.NET Core Web Application). During the compilation process I'm getting this error message:

> ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: '/temp' is not a valid IIS application.

So how can I compile the views as a syntax checking in ASP.NET Core MVC 1?

Comment: I think this feature is in iis, if you are using kestrel to serve your application. it might be the problem?

Comment: And take a look at these:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662225/how-to-check-asp-net-core-rc2-1-0-razor-views-for-compile-errors
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518206/does-mvc6-support-precompiled-views

Comment: I can't believe such a valid question has not received an answer yet.